# Sqlite update DATETIME field not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to update a DATETIME column in a Sqlite table using the following query.

```
String query = "UPDATE myTable SET displayed = datetime('now') where _id = " + id;
database.rawQuery(query, null);
```

I have tested this on both device and emulator but its not working, its not updating the value in the column.

PS: I tried the same query in Sqlite browser and its working there.

Please help me figure out a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: not working? do you get an error?

Comment: No error, field values remain same!

Comment: How about using `database.execSQL()`?

Comment: Let me give it a shot.

Comment: I think your issues is your non-escaped quotes. `datetime('now')` should be `datetime(\'now\')`

Comment: It worked using database.execSQL() :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `rawQuery()`, use `execSQL()` if the execution doesn't return any data.

```
String query = "UPDATE myTable SET displayed = datetime('now') where _id = " + id;
database.execSQL(query);
```

Though just a tip, it is better to use UNIX time if you really want to store and process date in the future. It will be more flexible and standardized.

Comment: Could please explain how to UNIX time, I will make the required changes, just give me hint? Thanks

Comment: UNIX time is a millisecond from 1970-1-1 in UTC/GMT, so basically you will store a number (`long`) instead of text (though it doesn't really matter in SQLite since it's typeless). To get current time, there are some ways. Some example are `new Date().getTime()` or `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()`. Later, if you want to have the text representation of the date, you can use `DateFormat` or `SimpleDateFormat` class as the helper.